# How to make a new DOM element to think it resides in a different domain with js and css

Tags: javascript, css

i'm creating a new dom element:

```
var bubbleDOM = document.createElement('div');
bubbleDOM.setAttribute('class', 'selection_bubble');
document.body.appendChild(bubbleDOM);
```

then i populate data to this DOM in a manner of text using .responseText with
XMLHttpRequest and finally change it's css:

```
.selection_bubble {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Everything works great until now. my problem is that a part of the data i've populated to
the DOM element has a href link such as:
/prop.php?id=333

which makes them think the link is really coming from my website, so when the user clicks on it he goes to:
http://www.mywebsite.com/prop.php?id=333

and i want those links to appear from the website (which i know it's name and there is
only one i'm pulling the data from) as they should be:
http://www.thesitei'mpullingfrom.com/prop.php?id=333

How can i change this either with CSS or JS?

Comment: Run a simple regex replacement against the responseText before placing it in the DOM? Like `responseText.replace(/mywebsite/g, "thesiteimpullingfrom")`

Comment: I missed the point of the URLs being relative to the server root. In this case you should replace them like this: `responseText.replace(/(href=")([^"]+)"/g, "$1http://thesiteimpullingfrom.com$2\"")`

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov that almost did the trick but had effect on all the links.. i need only those that start with an / please mark this as a question so i can approve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve my original comment on the question:

In order to fix only the URLs that start with a slash (/), something like the following command should be run:

(edited in accordance with the comment fixing the expression)

`responseText.replace(/(href=")(\/[^"]+)"/g, "$1http://thesiteimpullingfrom.com$2\"")`

Comment: Apologies, should be `responseText.replace(/(href=")(\/[^"]+)"/g, "$1http://thesiteimpullingfrom.com$2\"")` (escaped forward slash). Just tested in a JS console.

Answer (score 0):

Parse the (X)HTML into a DOM `Object` then get all the anchor `Element`s and replace their href attributes. E.g.:

```
var i = 0, n ;
var l ;
var s ;

    l = dom.getElementsByTagName("a") ;
    for( n = l.length; i < n ; i++ ) {
          o = l[i] ;
          if(  !!  ( s = o.getAttribute("href") )  ) {
                // add domain to s
                o.setAttribute("href") ;
          }
    }
```

Comment: That depends on the source and the browser. Can you go into detail a bit on what you want to insert?